# How to correctly move application data to an attached disk on an Azure Linux VM

Tags: linux, mount, hard-drive, azure

I have a Linux VM on Azure that originally came with a 30G OS disk. As I had an application that had accumulated a lot of data, I attached a new disk through the Azure Dashboard and here is how it looks like now:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/sda1        29G   19G  9.2G  67% /
none            4.0K     0  4.0K   0% /sys/fs/cgroup
udev            3.4G   12K  3.4G   1% /dev
tmpfs           698M  248K  697M   1% /run
none            5.0M     0  5.0M   0% /run/lock
none            3.5G     0  3.5G   0% /run/shm
none            100M     0  100M   0% /run/user
/dev/sdb1       281G   63M  267G   1% /mnt/resource
```

So `/mnt/resource` is the new disk that was attached. I moved all the application data to `/mnt/resource` and created a symlink on the original location pointing to the new location:

```
tomcat@jenkins:~$ ll
lrwxrwxrwx 1 tomcat  tomcat  21 Apr 18 22:14 .tomcat -> /mnt/resource/.tomcat/
```

My question is: Is the above a reliable solution, meaning that the attached disk and the data on it is always reliably available when the system starts, as it has to be mounted? Are there in general better solutions to solve the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NO it is NOT!**
/mnt/resource or /mnt (in Ubuntu VMs) is a temporary storage, Microsoft does not guarantee any data being saved in that location between reboots or downtime.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, this should work reliably since the data disk is treated no differently than an OS Disk for the purpose of reliability.

Since the backing disk is a VHD, an alternative would be to download the VHD and resize it using some tools available for this purpose. Then you can attach the VHD to a VM (maybe on HyperV itself, for simplicity) and resize your Ext partition.